# Jquery appending values to dropdown from select

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to return values within my dependant dropdown within laravel.  The api/dropdown returns json, all working fine. However the values returned are not populated in my dropdown, rather they are displaying [object Object] instead.

Am I missing something?

```
  $(document).ready(function($){

      $('#firstselect').change(function(){

            $.get("{{ url('api/dropdown')}}", { option: $(this).val() }, 
            function(data) {
                     $.each(data, function(key, value) {   
                         $('#secondselect')
                             .append($("<option></option>")
                             .attr("value",key)
                             .text(value)); 
                    });

            });

        });

    });
```

Comment: When you log the values in console, what do you see?

Comment: post the JSON you get from `api/dropdown`

Comment: can you post what data got in data object..I think you need to go 1 level down in JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.each(data,function(index,value){

//Make sure value is the string you want to attach by putting a debugger here;
//Append code;

  $('#secondselect').append($("<option></option>")
                         .attr("value",key)
                         .text(value));

});
```

In the code posted by you

```
  $(document).ready(function($){

      $('#firstselect').change(function(){

            $.get("{{ url('api/dropdown')}}", { option: $(this).val() }, 
            function(data) {
                     $.each(data, function(key, value) {   

                /**********************************************/
                //Evaluate and make sure value is string
                debugger;
                console.log(value);
               /*************************************************/

                   $('#secondselect').append($("<option></option>")
                             .attr("value",key)
                             .text(value)); 
                    });

            });

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

USe $.parseJSON  to fetch values ferom object

```
 function(data) {
 data =  $.parseJSON(data);
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xL48aqgw/1/)

html

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

jquery

```
$(function () {
    var $val = "Random";
         $('select').append('<option value="'+$val+'">'+$val+'</option>');

        });
```

hope it helps..